# Problemas con PHP Calendar Bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

Estoy trabajando en una agenda de reuniones con la libreria de php calendar y bootstrap, hasta ahora todo bien pero hay un problema que no logro resolver, es la parte que muestra en el calendario todas las reuniones, resulta que hay varios usuario y en la fecha que muestra la reunion hay una opcion de eliminar reunion y editar reunion, pero aparecen en todas las reuniones de todas las areas, y no deberia, deberia aparecer solamente al usuario logueado o segun el title(area) del usuario, les dejo el codigo a ver si algjuien me puede ayudar con eso.

Pagina week-days.html

Yo le hice un if al title Sistemas y a Escuelas, pero cuando se loguea por ejemplo Deposito, lo mismo se ve oculto todos menos sistema y escuelas, ya no se que hacer. Nunca he trabajado con una plantilla html embedida en php de esa forma.

Los usuario los manejo con una variable de session, intente poner una sesion en esa pagina pero no muestra el calendario.

```
<% _.each(events, function(event) { %>
<div class="cal-row-fluid">
    <div class="cal-cell<%= event.days %> cal-offset<%= event.start_day %> day-highlight dh-<%= event['class'] %>"
         data-event-class="<%= event['class'] %>">

        <a href="<%= event.url ? event.url : 'javascript:void(0)' %>" data-event-id="<%= event.id %>"
           class="cal-event-week event<%= event.id %>"><span class="badge bg-warning text-dark"><%= event.title %></span></a>

<div>
                    
<% if (event.title == 'Sistemas') { %>

  <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <a href="<%= event.url2 ? event.url2 : 'javascript:void(0)' %>" data-event-id="<%= event.id %>" class="cal-event-week event<%= event.id %>">
    <span class="editar">Editar</span>
  </a>

  <a href='procesar_eliminar_evento.php?id=<%= event.id %>' alt="ELIMINAR REUNION" title="ELIMINAR REUNION">
    <i class="fa fa-times-circle" onClick="return confirmar()"></i>
    <span class="eliminar" onClick="return confirmar()">Eliminar</span>
  </a>

<% } else{ %>
  <!-- Ocultar editar para otros títulos -->
  <div class="ocultar">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <a href="<%= event.url2 ? event.url2 : 'javascript:void(0)' %>" data-event-id="<%= event.id %>" class="cal-event-week event<%= event.id %>">
      <span class="editar">Editar</span>
    </a>
    
    <div>    
      <a href='procesar_eliminar_evento.php?id=<%= event.id %>' alt="ELIMINAR REUNION" title="ELIMINAR REUNION">
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle" onClick="return confirmar()"></i>
        <span class="eliminar" onClick="return confirmar()">Eliminar</span>
      </a>      
    </div>
  </div>

<% } %>
            
<% if(event['title'] == 'Escuelas'){ %>

<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<a href="<%= event.url2 ? event.url2 : 'javascript:void(0)' %>" data-event-id="<%= event.id %>" class="cal-event-week event<%= event.id %>">
  <span class="editar">Editar</span>
</a>
           
<a href='procesar_eliminar_evento.php?id=<%= event.id %>' alt="ELIMINAR REUNION" title="ELIMINAR REUNION">
<i class="fa fa-times-circle" onClick="return confirmar()"></i>
<span class="eliminar" onClick="return confirmar()">Eliminar</span>
</a>
          

<% } else { %>
<div class="ocultar">
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<a href="<%= event.url2 ? event.url2 : 'javascript:void(0)' %>" data-event-id="<%= event.id %>" class="cal-event-week event<%= event.id %>">
<span class="editar">Editar</span></a>
      
<div>    
<a href='procesar_eliminar_evento.php?id=<%= event.id %>' alt="ELIMINAR REUNION" title="ELIMINAR REUNION">
<i class="fa fa-times-circle" onClick="return confirmar()"></i>
<span class="eliminar" onClick="return confirmar()">Eliminar</span>
</a>      
</div>
</div>
<% } %>

        </div>
        <!-- FIN BOTON EDITAR -->
    
    
    <!-- Agregar el código PHP para manejar la variable de sesión -->
            
            
        <!-- FUNCION DE CONFIRMACION ELIMINAR AREA -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function confirmar() {
                var respuesta = confirm("¿Está seguro que desea eliminar esta reunión? \n Esta operación no podrá deshacerse.");
                if (respuesta) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <!-- FIN CONTENIDO DE LA PAGINA -->
    </div>
</div>
<% }); %>
```

Desde ya agraezco cualquier ayuda posible.